# SQL: Converting number to time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database column having the following values

```
column (hh/mm/ss)
042336
050623
```

Now using sql i want to covert it to like

```
column
04:23:63:000
05:06:23:000
```

I have been trying to_date function but no success yet.

Comment: What is `:000`?

Comment: it is milliseconds...i want to append it as 000

Comment: does your original column is  CHAR/VARCHAR or else?

Comment: the original column is integer

Comment: An integer cannot have a leading `0`

Comment: perhaps this column is Varchar

Comment: I was about to tell the same. Explain how your column can contain `042336` if it is declared as INT.

Comment: The "perhaps" is not allowed here :). Figure out your column type first. If VARCHAR @GordonLinoff 's answer will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string so you can use string operations to insert the additional characters:

```
select (substr(x, 1, 2) || ':' || substr(x, 3, 2) || ':' || substr(x, 5, 2) || ':000')
from (select '042336' as x from dual) t
```

Comment: The seems to be a brut way of doing it....is it possible to do it via to_date or to_timestamp

Comment: It always end up in a brute way when you don't store date/time values in their correct declared types columns. That's the primary reason to never do it in the first place

Comment: @ThomasG . . . Integers don't start with `0`.  In addition, Oracle doesn't have a `time` data type, so there is not a lot of choice here .